# How to exclude all values when certain conditions met?

Tags: reporting-services

I am working with the following table and would like to return values where `Code` does not equal `__S__` while simultaneously excluding all the values for a particular `PartNo` if it does contain an `__S__`. In my example since this part number has a `Code` present of `__S__` I would want the other values excluded as well.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything is in a single table then you will need to do something like this.

```
SELECT a.* 
    FROM myTable a 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT PartNo FROM myTable WHERE Code = '__S__') x 
        ON a.PartNo = x.PartNo
    WHERE x.PartNo IS NULL
```

The subquery aliased as 'x' contains a list of the part numbers you want to exclude. So, we left join to this subquery and only select records where no join is found.